# Default debugger

Tags: visual-studio-code

when i run in vsc the code i might have cliked google chrome insted of nodejs
how do i revert that? becouse when i click run it just opens in chrome and do NOT give me the options as normal :(

i am using VSC: v1.77.3

edit: i have tried to re-install the VSC

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I met the same issue when I debug a vsc extension.

[image]

I chose the first option instead of the 2nd option by mistake.

I solved that by the following way:

1. create launch.json by the way easy to find .
2. open launch.json in editor, and click the button 'Add Configuration' on the bottom-right.

[image]

3. on the popup menu, select the debugger you want to use

[image]

4. vscode will generator a configuration item in the file. Editor that item if necessary.

[image]

5. Click 'run and debug' icon on left pane, choose the configuration item name you just set to start debugging.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

VSCode should have created a directory called `.vscode` inside the current workspace/folder. Inside, there should be a file named `launch.json`. Delete the `launch.json` file and run your code again.

Comment: it does not have a .vscode

Comment: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/824685083113553933/1100328995595243620/aDuXt4W.png

Comment: Check the entire workspace, not just the folder with the file. VScode cannot run code without prompting unless there is a `launch.json`

Comment: @B0tCreati0n If you still can’t find it, do this: open the command pallet (`Ctrl` + `Shift` + `P`) and type `Open launch.json`. If one doesn’t exist, click on `Run` in the menu bar, then select `Add Configuration`. It will then allow you to select you default debugger and will create the `launch.json` file for you